# Using JQuery .animate() to start at one value and end at another

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Is it possible to use jquery's .animate() method to animate properties from an (explicitly set) initial value to a final value, or must it always be from the current value to another value?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. To `.animate()`, what's the difference between *current value* and the *initial value*? A little more detail would be nice, along with some code examples to illustrate what you are trying to do. :)

Comment: Can't you just set your initial value before using `.animate()`?

Comment: @Alex- If I want to animate a div from off the page into it's normal place, I would start off with an outlying value for example.

Comment: @elusive- yes, just wondering if there was a more efficient way to do it all through the .animate() call, instead of having to reposition, then animate, each time

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I know it has to be current value to final value.  But lets say you want to animate height from 20 to 100px;  Just do:

```
$('#elem').css('height', '20px').animate({ height: 100 }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can simply specify start value by setting it as a pseudo-selector.

Let's consider that you need to animate some value that is not a CSS property from -100 to 100. In this case your code will be:

```
$({xyz: -100}).animate({xyz:100}, {duration:5000, complete:function(){
    console.log("done");
}, step: function(now) {
    //here you want to place your processing code for every frame of animation.
    console.log("Anim now: "+now);
}});
```

You can see working example at JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fE95s/).

Answer (score 2):

`.animate()` will always go from the currently set value of the property you're animating to the final value you specify with the method.  If you wanted to go from opacity 0.75 to 0.25 and your current value was 0.5 then you would need to do `.css('opacity',0.75).animate({opacity: 0.25})`

Answer (score 0):

Just set the value of the property before calling animate().